# a Sequential that decreased by 5 using a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

i want to print a Sequential that decreased by 5 
using a for loop 
but i don't know why it doesn't print the output :(

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    for(int j=60;j<=0;j-=5){
        cout<<j<<endl;
    }    
}
```

whats the wrong?!

Comment: Why on earth are you including `bits/stdc++.h`?  You should be including `iostream`.

Comment: as i know it is a library that includes all libraries

Comment: It isn't.  And it's also an implementation detail, it's not designed to be included by users.

Comment: mmm,so ,why it is designed for ?

Comment: As I said, it's an implementation detail.  The "public" headers include it internally, as and when required.  It's free to be modified at any time, so you can't safely include it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to

```
for(int j=60;j>=0;j-=5){
              ^^
```

Comment: Ohhh no , yesss you are right :D